# Angular 7 Horizontal Timeline Change line color for each milestone - Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I need to change the color of the horizontal line for the timeline based on  certain condition.

I am looking to have different line color based on completed milestone.  Like
Red from A to B and Green from B to D.

I am not sure how to approach this, any help would be helpful.

Also please let me know if any working example in internet.

here is my sample :
[image]

```css
#timeline-wrap {
  margin: 10% 10%;
  top: 100;
  position: relative;

}

#timeline {
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #aabbc4;
  position: relative;

}

.marker {
  z-index: 1000;
  color: #fff;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -25px;
  background-color: #999999;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.marker:hover {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  -o-transform: scale(1.2);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);

  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}


.timeline-icon.one {
  background-color: rgb(249, 23, 56) !important;
}

.timeline-icon.two {
  background-color: #536295 !important;
}

.timeline-icon.three {
  background-color: #6976a2 !important;
}

.timeline-icon.four {
  background-color: #7e8aaf !important;
}


.mfirst {
  top: -13px;
}

.m2 {
  top: -13px;
  left: 32.5%
}

.m3 {
  top: -13px;
  left: 66%;
}


.mlast {
  top: -13px;
  left: 100%
}
```

```html
<ul id="timeline-wrap" style="padding-left: 0">

        <div id="timeline"></div>

        <!-- This is the individual marker-->
        <li class="marker mfirst timeline-icon one">
          <i class="fa fa-pencil">A</i>
        </li>
        <!-- / marker -->
        
        <!-- This is the individual marker-->
        <li class="marker m2 timeline-icon two">
          <i class="fa fa-usd">B</i>
        </li>
        <!-- / marker -->

        <!-- This is the individual marker-->
        <li class="marker m3 timeline-icon three">
          <i class="fa fa-list">C</i>
        </li>
        <!-- / marker -->


        <!-- This is the individual marker-->
        <li class="marker mlast timeline-icon four">
          <i class="fa fa-check">D</i>
        </li>
        <!-- / marker -->



      </ul>
```

Comment: It will be better if you draw separate segments instead of trying to do changing part of the div line color. Easier & manageable.

Comment: @AmitabhDas can you show some example pls. Sorry, I am basically backend developer getting my hands on UI and still learning things.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a stackblitz for it: [check it out](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gkzyjw)

With ngStyle you can set a style dynamically

```
<div [ngStyle]="{backgroundColor: getColor()}" class="timeline" ></div>

<li (click)="a = !a" class="marker mfirst timeline-icon one">
  <i class="fa fa-pencil">A</i>
</li>
```

This code is only an example, their are better ways to do it. It should give you a little hunch which way you can go.

```
 getColor(): string{
    if(this.d || this.c) {
      return 'green';
    }
    if(this.b || this.a) {
      return 'red';
    }
  }
```

And make sure not to use !important in your css. It's only for worst case situations

Comment: Thanks I have manipulated that. I want the line color to change like attached image in description